# Как держать сессии во всех браузерах?

Tags: php, ajax, cookie, laravel, аутентификация

Веб-приложение для ВК на Laravel, Nginx, PHP-FPM. Посетитель приходит с ключом в GET-параметрах, сервер проверяет валидность ключа, и если ключ валидный, записывает какие-то данные в сессию и отдаёт HTML главной страницы динамического приложения. Далее с клиента поступают Ajax-запросы, и перед выполнением каждого фильтр авторизации проверяет, есть ли в сессии определённые данные.

Сессии PHP держатся на куки. Но, как выяснилось, в редких случаях у людей не поддерживаются куки, и последующие Ajax-запросы приходят без куки.

Ладно, зато они приходят с указанием реферера – основной страницы, включая все GET-параметры. По ним тоже можно быстро проверить валидность запроса.

Теперь выяснилось, что ещё есть редкие индивиды, у которых и это не срабатывает! Свежий Chrome, возможно, какие-то настройки приватности, или режим Incognito, или расширение блокирует и куки, и реферера.

Как держать сессии в таком случае?

Костыль (?) планирую пока такой: в первом авторизованном GET-параметрами запросе отдавать в странице какой-то уникальный ключ сессии и добавлять его при каждом Ajax-запросе для подтверждения валидности запроса. Так должно работать, но сомневаюсь, что это «белое», «правильное» решение.

Как правильно держать сессию, когда клиент не хочет ни куки, ни реферера светить?

Comment: "Правильность" у каждого своя, но я бы отсылал в каждом запросе GET-параметром. И на практике такое использую, и звучит для меня как более-менее универсальное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Для отправки с использованием `jQuery`, насколько я помню надо добавить параметр:

```
$.ajax( {
   /* Setup the call */
   xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
   }
 });
```

А лучше, если вы знакомы с `REST API` то там для аутентификации используются токены, посылаемые каждый раз в теле запроса. Это наиболее правильный подход.

И это не костыль, а подход используемый всеми при работе с `AJAX` и `REST`. По мне так сессии на основе куки это костыль для протокола `HTTP`, который изначально без сохранения состояния.

Только надо обязательно серьезно продумать аутентификацию по токенам и привязать как минимум к `IP` адресу.